# fancyhdr color and width of line?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am using the fancyhdr package and I want to have a thicker line under my header and I want to have it colored, but my problem is, that this 2 commands:

```
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox
to\headwidth{\textcolor{headercolor}{\hrulefill}}\vss}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
```

Do not work together? So how can I get a more thicker line which is also colored?

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{left=4cm,right=3cm, top=2cm, bottom=2cm} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-30pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 

\usepackage{xcolor,bookmark}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{titlepic}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{courier}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{type1cm}         
\usepackage{zref-abspage}



    \usepackage{makeidx}        

    \usepackage{graphicx}                                         
  \usepackage{multicol}       
   \usepackage{thmbox}
    \usepackage{shadethm}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{marginnote}
    %\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{paralist}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
    \usepackage{ulem}
    \usepackage{fancyheadings}
    %\usepackage{sectsty}

    \definecolor{headercolor}{rgb}{0.6941,0.6745,0.4863}


    \begin{document}

\mainmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{part1} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{ \textcolor{headercolor}\leftmark \text{ }\textcolor{headercolor}{\thesection}}
\fancyhead[R]{\textcolor{headercolor}{\thepage}}
%\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vbox to 0pt{\hbox
%to\headwidth{\textcolor{headercolor}{\hrulefill}}\vss}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}
 test test\\ test test    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't sent "complete code" which includes files we don't have. Sent a small example that we can compile and so use for tests. Also use `fancyhdr` instead of `fancyheadings` which is obsolete.

Comment: I now merged your two accounts together. You should be able to edit your question again and comment to answers to it. Please consider registering an account to avoid this hassle in the future. Or, at least, try to keep one unregistered account (Cookies enabled?).

Answer (score 27):

You need to incorporate `\headrulewidth` inside your redefinition of `\headrule`, since `\hrulefill` uses a different width rule:

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}% 2pt header rule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
  \color{headercolor}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
```

Here's an informal MWE that uses the above technique to construct the page style `myheader`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{fancyhdr}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\fancypagestyle{myheader}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear all headers/footers
  \fancyhead[C]{My header}% Header Centred
  \fancyfoot[C]{-\thepage-}% Footer Centred
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}% 2pt header rule
  \renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
    \color{red}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}
\setlength{\headheight}{21pt}%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myheader}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Werner!
Can I also have the text in the header ('My header') to be on the header line directly, instead of being vertically centered in the header? I think this is due, to the created \hbox if I'm not mistaken?? Thanks

Comment: @marinko: I suggest trying something like `\fancyhead[C]{\raisebox{-.5\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{My header}}`. This lowers the `My header` 1/2 a baseline skip and completely removes the depth/height of the resulting change (to avoid any possible warnings in your `.log`).