# Changing color in newlfm headline

Tags: header-footer, color, newlfm

I would like to change color of the Headline and Footline in `newlfm` package.
I have changed width of the line using:

```
\newlfmP{Headlinewd=4pt,Footlinewd=4pt}
```

and now I would like to change the color of these lines for

```
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{29,57,127}
```

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The head and foot rules are produced using `\headrule` and `\footrule`. You can easily patch them to produce colored rules with the help of the `etoolbox` package.

```
\documentclass{newlfm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newlfmP{Headlinewd=4pt,Footlinewd=4pt}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{29,57,127}

\pretocmd\headrule{\color{myblue}}{}{}
\pretocmd\footrule{\color{myblue}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
Text
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`newlfm`](//ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) uses [`fancyhdr`](//ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) to set the headers/footers of the letter. To that end, you can follow the instructions in [`fancyhdr` color and width of line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69950/5764) or redefine `\headrule` and `\footrule` directly from [`fancyhdr.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty):

[image]

```
\documentclass{newlfm}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{29,57,127}
\newlfmP{Headlinewd=4pt,Footlinewd=4pt}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{myblue}\hrule height \headrulewidth width \headwidth
  \vskip-\headrulewidth}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
  \color{myblue}\hrule width \headwidth height \footrulewidth \vskip\footruleskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{newlfm}
Some letter content.
\end{newlfm}

\end{document}
```

In general, there is no need to use `newlfm`, as it can easily be substituted for the regular `article` class.

Comment: Why the `\hbox` and `\leaders`? The `fancyhdr` documentation shows `\renewcommand{\headrule}{{\color{red}\hrule...\vskip-\headrulewidth}}`. I don't think I've ever used `\leaders` directly, so this may not apply, but it looks like you need the `\vskip-\headrulewidth`.

Comment: @TH.: Correct. I've updated it based on the content within [`fancydr.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.sty).