# Change horizontal line color on top of footer

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to change the colour of the horizontal line directly above the footer. I have referenced [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69950/fancyhdr-color-and-width-of-line) question and copied the relevant code below. This successfully changes the color of the horizontal line at the bottom of the header. However, I am unable to manipulate it to change the color of the line at the top of the footer.

```
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
  \renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{mycustomcolor}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
```

I tried changing the `\headrule` to `\footrule` in the second line but it did not work and I do not have a solid understanding of how to make the correct changes to apply it to the footer.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Using the code in Werner's answer to the linked question and changing `\headrule` to `\footrule` works for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works....

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{red}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{red}\leaders\hrule height \footrulewidth\hfill}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems to change the position of the separator, though? (the vertical space between the header and the line is larger)

Comment: @Rastapopoulos yes you are right, please how to decrease the vertical space between line-header?

Answer (score 4):

JPi's answer works but adds extra space. This extra space is expected and accounted for in the standard definitions of `\headrule` and `\footrule` in `fancyhdr.sty` as follows.

```
\def\headrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\headrulewidth\plainheadrulewidth\fi
    \hrule\@height\headrulewidth\@width\headwidth \vskip-\headrulewidth}}

\def\footrule{{\if@fancyplain\let\footrulewidth\plainfootrulewidth\fi
    \vskip-\footruleskip\vskip-\footrulewidth
    \hrule\@width\headwidth\@height\footrulewidth\vskip\footruleskip}}
```

Note the `\vskip` at the end of each definition above.

Here is a trick that does not redefine the line drawing, rather adds color to the standard definitions.

```
% Save standard definitions
\let\HeadRule\headrule
\let\FootRule\footrule
% Add color to standard definitions.
\renewcommand\headrule{\color{red}\HeadRule}
\renewcommand\footrule{\textcolor{red}{\FootRule}}
```

You will notice that the renewed definitions of `\headrule` and `\footrule` do not use the same command for coloring. The redefinition of `\headrule` uses the `\color` command as using `\textcolor` ends up adding space. The redefinition of `\footrule` uses the `\textcolor` command as using `\color` ends up coloring any footer text.

Here is an MWE along the lines of JPi's answer.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{\headrulewidth}
% Save standard definitions
\let\HeadRule\headrule
\let\FootRule\footrule
% Add color to standard definitions.
\renewcommand\headrule{\color{red}\HeadRule}
\renewcommand\footrule{\textcolor{red}{\FootRule}}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{Left Head}
\rhead{Right Head}
\cfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}
Hello, world!

\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

and here is the first page of the compiled output.
[image: page showing colored header and footer lines]

Comment: This does work. Thanks a lot.