# Change the color of the header line

Tags: color, fancyhdr, rules

The answer to the question [fancyhdr - Change horizontal line color on top of footer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375121/change-horizontal-line-color-on-top-of-footer) is not completely satisfactory, because it changes the position of the header line,
for example with this example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{red}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{Hello}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
    hello
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to change only the color of the line, without changing its position?

Comment: A simple `\renewcommand{\headrule}{{\color{red}\rule{\textwidth}{0.5pt}}}` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not (at least not on my computer).

Comment: The position of the line isn't changed, neither with your code nor with mine. How is it modified, precisely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below I save the original `\headrule` in `\oldheadrule`, and then prepend `\color{<colour>}` to a newly-defined `\headrule` that just calls `\oldheadrule`. The approach is similar to [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s `\pretocmd`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor}

\let\oldheadrule\headrule% Copy \headrule into \oldheadrule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{red}\oldheadrule}% Add colour to \headrule
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyhead{Hello}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum\ldots

\clearpage

Lorem ipsum\ldots

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had tried exactly this, but with `\newcommand{\oldheadrule}{\headrule}`, which resulted in an infinite loop.