# Colored headrule - fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, color, fancyhdr

Using the provided line of code [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69950/fancyhdr-color-and-width-of-line) changes successfully the header color but creates a gap between the headertext/colorbox(lheadtext, rheadtext) and the header:

[image]

Is there a way to color the header without the gap?

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{lhead text}
\chead{}
\rhead{\fcolorbox{black}{black}{
        \footnotesize\bfseries{\makebox[4em]
        {\color{white}rhead text}}}%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{blue}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}

\begin{document}
    text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you want to avoid the gap between the header text and the line below the header? You could patch `\headrule` to change the color of the line:

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{lhead text}
\chead{}
\rhead{\fcolorbox{black}{black}{
        \footnotesize\bfseries{\makebox[4em]
        {\color{white}rhead text}}}%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd\headrule{\color{blue}}{}{\PatchFailed}

\begin{document}
    text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that's it. I've never used `xpatch`befor. Thank you for your answer. I would guess, in the `xpatch`documentation there is more to find about the header customization?

Comment: @LeoCahron not on header customization no, esdd just uses knowledge about how `\headrule` is made, to know that one can just add `\color{blue}` to the front of that definition and get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use, \setlength{headsep} to tune the distance between the header and the text.

```
\documentclass[9pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\lhead{lhead text}
\chead{}
\rhead{\fcolorbox{black}{black}{
        \footnotesize\bfseries{\makebox[4em]
        {\color{white}rhead text}}}%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}

\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{\color{blue}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}

%% set the gap between header and text
\setlength{\headsep}{0.1in}

\begin{document}
    text
\end{document}
```

Hope it helps.

Romain

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately it is not what i was looking for. I am sorry for the (i admit) confusing question. It is updated now.

Answer (score 1):

```
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{red}\hrulefill}
```

Full code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xcolor}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{red}\hrulefill}
\lhead{Head}
\begin{document}
    Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excuse me. Can you put a complete code thus I understand your solution? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sebastiano I have just added the full code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your collaboration.